# Python script closes after a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm using Keras for the layers, optimizer, and model and my model is Sequential

I've got two DQN networks and I'm making them duel each other in a simulated environment however after about 35 episodes (different each time) the script just stops without any errors. I've isolated my issue to be somewhere around when the agent runs the prediction model for the current state to get the action. The process is called but never completed and the script just stops without any error. How can I debug this issue?

Comment: do you have a callback function with earlystopping when train the network?

Answer (score 1):

The way I was looping my function needed to be a for loop instead of directly calling the function as a loop method. And my error was a stack overflow